# What do I get for holding gyms?

Tags: pokemon-go

So far, gyms in my area flip so frequently that I haven't been able to hold more than one gym at a time when collecting my rewards. I know the reward for a single gym is 500 stardust and 10 coins.

Does this reward scale linearly with multiple gyms, or does it follow a different progression? I've also heard there might be some kind of bonus for holding a gym for more than a day, but haven't managed to do it. Is there a bonus for that (or any other kinds of bonuses)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pokemon go, gym, coins](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/275470/pokemon-go-gym-coins)

Comment: That talks about the timing of reclaiming gyms. It doesn't ask about the payout structure.

Comment: the comments and answers in that thread do not talk about any other bonus so, there is none. like you already know, every day, (500 stardust and 10 coin ) x pokemon defending gyms

Comment: I'd seen something on reddit/r/pokemongo (can't find the link now) that mentioned you get a bonus for holding a gym for more than one day, so I'm trying to find out if that's true or BS. Sounds like it was probably BS.

Comment: @sterno what kind of bonus? an extra part of the defender bonus or something else?

Comment: i've never read something like that...

Comment: They made it sound like extra coins. But there were no specifics. I trust your answer more than I trust reddit, but it partially prompted my question. That, and if it scaled non-linearly, I would have seen more value in trying for multiple gyms.

Comment: @Sterno protip: get gyms that can't be accessed by cars, even if it's a 10 second walk. They get taken over far less often.

Answer (score 10):

The reward scales linearly it's 500 dust and 10 coins per gym up to 5000 dust and 100 coins per defender bonus collection. You can collect your defender bonus if you haven't collected for at least 21 hours prior.

I have held gyms for multiple days and haven't seen any sort of bonus when collecting the defender bonus. Perhaps there is an xp bonus or something but I have never seen it in the journal so I doubt it exists.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently king of a level 10 gym, and have been for roughly 27 hours, I got no bonus other than the usual 10 coins and 500 stardust. So holding a gym for 24 hours just makes you feel special, and that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to go into the "Shop" and click on the shield in the top right corner. You can then collect a defender bonus every 21 hours from that point. 
I have no Pokemon at gyms rt now so I haven't been able to test that

Answer (score -2):

I have held for gyms for the day and there is a shield that you can collect stuff from in the shop. I got 2000 dust and 40 coins